# Extract Substring in BigQuery

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

| Body |
| --- |
| /tpt/TpScaning-ScaningRoad-PERSIVEE-202301020730327429-1567651.tp |
| /tpt/TpScaning-BaliResortsInterns-PERSIVEE-202205300341154744-909890.tp |
| /tpt/TpScaning-RXX-PERSIVEE-202108210412090110-000989.tp |
| /tpt/TpScaning-Backnationnotecom-PERSIVEE-202112201229124214-783672.tp |
| /tpt/TpScaning-DBZ-PERSIVEE-202109131129036172-908954.tp |
| /tpt/TpScaning-DBZ-PERSIVEE-202109131129036172-17892578.tp |

I have a column 'Body' in a BigQuery table xyz which contains the Scans being requested on our internal app. A Body field contains date part within it i.e. (202301020730327429, 202205300341154744 ...) the 18 digit numbers.

I want to extract this 18 digit sequence in the separate column named date to know when the scan requests were created.

I tried to use the substr function but it did not work correctly as the length of Body field is varying. Is there a better way to get this implemented?

Expected output:

| date |
| --- |
| 202301020730327429 |
| 202205300341154744 |
| 202108210412090110 |
| 202112201229124214 |
| 202109131129036172 |
| 202109131129036172 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider also below approach

```
select body, regexp_extract(body, r'\d{18}') as date,
  timestamp(regexp_replace(body, r'(^.*?)(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(.*?$)', r'\2-\3-\4 \5:\6:\7.\8')) as ts
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '/tpt/TpScaning-ScaningRoad-PERSIVEE-202301020730327429-1567651.tp' body UNION ALL
  SELECT '/tpt/TpScaning-BaliResortsInterns-PERSIVEE-202205300341154744-909890.tp' body UNION ALL
  SELECT '/tpt/TpScaning-RXX-PERSIVEE-202108210412090110-000989.tp' body UNION ALL
  SELECT '/tpt/TpScaning-Backnationnotecom-PERSIVEE-202112201229124214-783672.tp' body UNION ALL
  SELECT '/tpt/TpScaning-DBZ-PERSIVEE-202109131129036172-908954.tp' body UNION ALL
  SELECT '/tpt/TpScaning-DBZ-PERSIVEE-202109131129036172-17892578.tp' body
)
SELECT *, PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d%H%M%E4S', LEFT(date, 14) || '.' || RIGHT(date, 4)) ts 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, REGEXP_EXTRACT(body, r'\d{18}') AS date FROM sample_table
  );
```

###### some explanations

- regular expressions explanations -> https://regex101.com/r/fiB4mD/1
- `\d` matches 1 digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `{18}` matches the previous token exactly 18 times
- [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) function will find a pattern described in the regular expression above from a given string data.
- `%E4S` format element parse *seconds with  digits of fractional precision*, i.e. `00.0000 for %E4S`. note that it requires a dot(.) in string data.

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger, it works perfectly thank you:) can you explain me what exactly is happening here? I mean how does it work?

Comment: @Kushal, I've added some explanation for the regular expression used in the query. kindly check that out.

Comment: Thank you @Jaytiger. Also, can you help me further how to convert the same to utc timestamp? I tried using parse_timestamp it is not working for all the cases.

Comment: @Kushal, `202109131129036172` means `2021-09-13 11:29:03.6172` ?

Comment: Yesh.. correct!

Comment: @Kushal, it's not possible (as I know) to directly convert it to `timestamp`.  I've manipulated the `date` string and add a dot(.) so that we can apply `%E4S` format elemet.  kindly see my updated query

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I rather did this parse_timestamp('%Y%m%d%l%M%S', REGEXP_EXTRACT(body, r'\d{14}')) as request_timestamp